# Do I need to declare friends and family in UK when applying for a Standard Visitor visa?

Tags: paperwork, standard-visitor-visas

I am about to apply for a UK Standard Visitor visa on an Indian passport. I have sufficient funds as shown by bank statements and am a full-time employed permanent resident of Canada. The application requires me to state whether I have friends/family and then requires all their details (their status in UK, address etc). I have a few old friends and one cousin but do not want to add them because of the details required.

Do you think it is a plus point or can go against me if I say "NO" to *Do you have friends or family in UK*?

Comment: Take the extra time. If you are caught, your visa will be refused and you may attract a ban for up to 10 years!

Comment: Hmm, I have several online friends who claim convincingly to be located in the UK -- but I'm pretty sure that if I were to demand of them their full names, addresses and phone numbers, they would not be my friends anymore. (Problem solved?)

Answer (score 8):

**Do you think it is a plus point or can go against me if I say NO to "Do you have friends or family in UK".**

The truthful answer to this is 'yes', but you would like to answer 'no' because to answer truthfully involves going in to detail.  This is going to be a easy one.  Let's look at the head note to *[Kenya [2010] UKUT 165 (IAC)](https://tribunalsdecisions.service.gov.uk/utiac/2010-ukut-165)*...

> “When a direct question is asked, and answered untruthfully, there is
>   both a false representation and a non-disclosure; and it is not open
>   to an Appellant who gives an untruthful answer to a direct question in
>   an application form to say that the matter was not material.”

What this means is that if you get caught there will be very little room to argue  that you were justified in answering 'no' in order to avoid giving details.

So on that basis, it would not be a 'plus point' if you answer 'no' and they find out that someone else in your family (for example) had previously answered 'yes' or they learned through some other way.

It's actually difficult to find an internet resource that recommends lying on a UK visa application, and this site is no different.  Avoid deception.

---

Note: screen shot of the guidance...

[image]

Also......

[image]

Comment: I understand but the friends are not close enough that I can ask them their details like their status in UK. Same with family, it is just some distant cousin whom I will not like to ask about their details. I may inform them once I get there if they are willing to meet.

Comment: This raises an interesting point.  What is the definition of friend or family?  I have several second cousins in the UK. As far as I remember, I have met only one of them, once, about 42 years ago.  I don't even know all of their names.  Would I need to find out?  What about their possible children? Where does one draw the line? Do I have to list every British person I've ever met? Is there room to list them all in the online application form?

Comment: Your choices are to (a) answer "yes" and find out all the information they want, (b) answer "yes" and say "don't know" about the things you don't actually know, or (c) lie and say "no".  (a) clearly makes the cleanest, most complete application, but if you don't know and can't or don't want to find out I'd still choose (b) over (c).  All my experience (generally, not just UK-specific) says that if you lie on an immigration application and somehow get caught you are doomed; it is always better to tell the truth as you know it and let them decide if they care about what you don't know.

Comment: Is there an official definition of family for UK immigration purposes? The term "cousin" covers first cousins, second cousins, etc.

Comment: @GayotFow: Probably not -- where does one find that guidance? When I try to find out what the application form even looks like, gov.uk keeps redicecting me to https://www.visa4uk.fco.gov.uk/ which refuses to tell me anything unless i "register an account" first.

Comment: Hmm .. you find the form by starting at gov.uk and then clicking "visas and immigration", "Tourist and short-stay visas" and then **not** "Standard Visitor visa" but **instead** "Visas and immigration operational guidance", "Fees and forms", "UK visa, immigration and citizenship application forms", and finally "Application for UK visa to visit or for short-term stay: form VAF1A" to arrive at https://www.gov.uk/government/publications/application-for-uk-visa-to-visit-or-for-short-term-stay-form-vaf1a

Comment: @GayotFow: I fail to see the relevance of that.

Comment: From the guidance, it looks as if a cousin does not count as family. That leaves the question of friends, but what the original poster writes does not sound like a close personal relationship.